# Meteor - "each" listing in view

Tags: html, meteor

I have this part of code:

```
{{#each cards}}
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="card span4">
            <p>{{content}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

and issue with setting it up to do something like this:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="card span4">
        <p>{{content}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card span4">
        <p>{{content}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card span4">
        <p>{{content}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="card span4">
        <p>{{content}}</p>
    </div>
....
```

Anyone have any idea how to do so? (I know that I can render directly from `Meteor.render()` but I want to avoid it if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this `split` helper function which will split an `array` into sub-arrays, each with up to `n` elements:

```js
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Handlebars.registerHelper("split", function(array, n) {
    var groups = _.groupBy(array, function(element, index) {
      return Math.floor(index/n);
    });

    return _.toArray(groups);
  });

}
```

```html
{{#each split cards 3}}
  <div class="row-fluid">
    {{#each this}}
      <div class="card span4">
        <p>{{content}}</p>
      </div>
    {{/each}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Note that your `cards` helper function must return an array for this to work, not a collection cursor.

Comment: Works great! Thank you very much! And there is a good lesson for me that I can use helpers in view.